# Arranging array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing categories and subcategories. I need to arrange this so that the 'next_id' of parent contain the id of its subcategory and then move to next parent category.
Please help.

http://codepad.org/mDm0cZiw

```
$master=array
(
    '97' => array
        (
            'name' => '★ CLOTHING',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'path' => 97,
            'next_id' => 51
        ),

    '51'=> array
        (
            'name' => '★ GO GIRL +',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'path' => 51,
            'next_id' => 126,
        ),


    '98' => array
        (
            'name' => '★ SARONGS & KAFTANS',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'path' => 98,
            'next_id' => 129
        ),

    '129' => array
        (
            'name' => '★ SHAPEWEAR',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'path' => 129,
            'next_id' => 127
        ),

    '127'=> array
        (
            'name' => '--------------------------------',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'path' => 127,
            'next_id' => 38
        ),



   '87' => array
        (
            'name' => '★ FOOTWEAR',
             'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'path' => 87,
            'next_id' => 119
        ),

    '119' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ BOTTOMS',
            'parent' => 97,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '97_119',
            'next_id' => 99
        ),

    '99' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ KAFTANS',
             'parent' => 98,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '98_99',
            'next_id' => 139
        ),

    '139' => array
        (
            'name' => 'IPANEMA',
            'parent' => 87,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '87_139',
            'next_id' => 132
        ),

    '132' => array
        (
            'name' => 'RENIU LOTIONS - Retail Only',
            'parent' => 38,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '38_132',
            'next_id' => 133
        ),

    '133' => Array
        (
            'name' => 'SUNGLASSES - Retail Only',
            'parent' => 38,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '38_133',
            'next_id' => 140
        ),

    '140' => array
        (
            'name' => 'THERAPY',
             'parent' => 87,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '87_140',
            'next_id' => 131
        ),

    '131' => array
        (
            'name' => 'WATCHES - Retail Only',
             'parent' => 38,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '38_131',
            'next_id' => 85
        ),

    '85' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ ALL ABOUT EVE - Retail',
            'parent' => 100,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '100_85',
            'next_id' => 102
        ),

    '102' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ ONE SUMMER - Retail',
             'parent' => 100,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '100_102',
            'next_id' => 39
        ),

    '39' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ TOPS',
            'parent' => 97,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '97_39',
            'next_id' => 84
        ),

    '84' => array
        (
            'name' => 'KEY CHARMS',
            'parent' => 38,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '38_84',
            'next_id' => 69
        ),

    '69' => array
        (
            'name' => 'RINGS',
            'parent' => 117,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '117_69',
            'next_id' => 42
        ),

    '42' => array
        (
            'name' => 'SCARVES',
            'parent' => 38,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '38_42',
            'next_id' => 31
        ),

    '31' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ DRESSES',
             'parent' => 97,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '97_31',
            'next_id' => 94
        ),

    '94' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ PLAYSUITS',
             'parent' => 97,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '97_94',
            'next_id' => 118
        ),

    '118' => array
        (
            'name' => 'BELTS',
             'parent' => 38,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '38_118',
            'next_id' => 50
        ),

    '50' => array
        (
            'name' => '☆ SARONGS',
             'parent' => 98,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '98_50',
            'next_id' => 26
        ),

    '26' => array
        (
            'name' => 'EARRINGS',
             'parent' => 117,
            'level' => 1,
            'path' => '117_26',
            'next_id' => 40
        ),



);
```

Comment: please define "'next_id' of parent"

Comment: Add your attempt in the question and what's your expected output?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

A flat structure like the one you have isn't bad. I would try to change my code to fit the data rather than change the data to fit the code.

You could do the following:

```
foreach($master as $id => $category)
    if($category['parent'] != 0 && isset($master[$category['parent']]['children']))
        $master[$category['parent']]['children'][$id] = $id;
    else
        $master[$category['parent']]['children'] = array($id => $id); 
 // $id => $id automatically remove possible duplicates use array($id) and [] if you don't want/need this.
```

so you have a link from your parent to the children. Then you can use a recursive function to handle your data.

```
function display($id)
{
    global $master;
    // output element
    if(isset($master[$id]['children'])) foreach($master[$id]['children'] as $child)
        display($child);
}
```

If you need to preverse the order try something like this:

```
function display($id)
{
    global $master;
    // output element
    $next_id = reset($master[$id]['children']); // i don't know how to better identify the first child
    while($next_id != 0){
        display($next_id);
        $next_id = $master[$next_id]['next_id'];
    }
    if($master[$id]['next_id'] != 0)
        display($master[$id]['next_id']);
}
```

I think this last one is the one you want.
I hope this gives you a idea of what I mean.